# Peformance Testing in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, testing, sharepoint-2010, performance-testing

I have created a Performance test in VS2010 for an sharepoint webapplication.

I Got few idicators like KeyIndecators,Page Response time etc...

Question 1:Please Briefly explain what are those graphs and how can we get the performance of a sharepoint site from those?

Question 2:I perform the testing in my local machine and i got the CPU utilization of my machine....How can i get the server's Utilization whare the sharepoint site created?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: page response time is exactly what the name implies - how long the page took to respond.  You'd be best off reading the user manual to get definitions and examples of what metrics are displayed and how to get the ones you really want.

Question 2: You'll need to talk with the sys admins who control the sharepoint server.  They can either give you access to monitoring tools, or give you the log data.